# JFreeChart different colors in different regions for the same dataSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart, renderer

In `JFreeChart` I'm trying to color different regions of an XY line chart/curve based on `y` value.  I'm overriding the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`'s  `getItemPaint(int row, int col)`, however I'm not sure how it handles the coloring of the line between the `x`s since it's only getting `itemPaint` on the `x` (integer values).

```
final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer() {
    @Override

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(col+","+dataset.getY(row, col));
        double y=dataset.getYValue(row, col);
        if(y<=3)return ColorUtil.hex2Rgb("#7DD2F7");
        if(y<=4)return ColorUtil.hex2Rgb("#9BCB3B");
        if(y<=5)return ColorUtil.hex2Rgb("#FFF100");
        if(y<=6)return ColorUtil.hex2Rgb("#FAA419");
        if(y<=10)return ColorUtil.hex2Rgb("#ED1B24");

        //getPlot().getDataset(col).
        return super.getItemPaint(row,col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the handling of the colouring between lines is implemented in `drawFirstPassShape`

The line colour appears to be based on the preceding point

[image]

This modification to your `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` uses a gradient fill to blend the line colour.

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
            Paint cpaint = getItemColor(row, col);
            if (cpaint == null) {
                cpaint = super.getItemPaint(row, col);
            }
            return cpaint;
        }

    public Color getItemColor(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(col + "," + dataset.getY(row, col));
        double y = dataset.getYValue(row, col);
        if(y<=3) return Color.black;
        if(y<=4) return Color.green;;
        if(y<=5) return Color.red;;
        if(y<=6) return Color.yellow;;
        if(y<=10) return Color.orange;;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawFirstPassShape(Graphics2D g2, int pass, int series,
        int item, Shape shape) {
        g2.setStroke(getItemStroke(series, item));
        Color c1 = getItemColor(series, item);
        Color c2 = getItemColor(series, item - 1);
        GradientPaint linePaint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, 300, c2);
        g2.setPaint(linePaint);
        g2.draw(shape);
    }
};
```

[image]

I've removed `ColorUtil.hex2Rgb` as I don't have access to that class/method.  You may want to modify `GradientPaint` to take account of the distance/gradient between points.