# How can i assign different colors to each dot in scatter plot using jfreechart in java?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am a newbie to Java and using JFreechart to display scatter plot.I have a thread which keeps adding points to scatter plot.Color of these points can be different depending upon some property(That is known,not the issue).Currently i am using "XYItemrenderer.setSeriesPaint(0,Color.black);"
to change the color but it changes color of all the points.I tried searching and found this-

[JFreeChart different colors in different regions for the same dataSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962836/jfreechart-different-colors-in-different-regions-for-the-same-dataseries)

But i am confused about how can i pass that information which decides the color of dot to  method?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that points differ depending upon some property is the *central* issue: the defining property needed to assign color is now an attribute of your data model. You can easily change the color in your view's renderer by overriding `getItemPaint()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285922/230513). The problem then becomes one of accessing the model from the view. The example cited simply references an attribute of the enclosing class, but you may want to pass a model reference to the view explicitly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as i mentioned color of dot is decided based on some other quality and this quality has no relation with row and column number. I found a solution by adding different colored dots to different series.

Comment: Multiple series is one approach, but it may scale poorly; the view should interrogate the model for the information it needs to render itself.

Comment: @trashgod. How did you get that shadow effect on the picture in your answer?

Comment: It's a feature of the Mac OS X [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).