# How to not draw segments of a time series in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

We are trying to not draw certain segments in a timeseries jFreeChart.

I have tried this solution but for me the dataset is always null so not sure what I am doing wrong.
[JFreeChart - change SeriesStroke of chart lines from solid to dashed in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240410/jfreechart-change-seriesstroke-of-chart-lines-from-solid-to-dashed-in-one-line)

Here is an example of our graph with gaps and we'd like to have the connecting line not rendered or maybe a dashed line at the very least.
[image]
Here is the code I've tried:

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer minuteRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer() {
    Stroke solid = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
    @Override
    public Stroke getItemStroke(int row, int column) {
        if (dataset == null) {
            System.out.println("why am I null?");
            return solid;
        }
    }
};
```

Could someone advise?

UPDATE: adding surrounding code for clarification. Note I do have a valid data set because it is plotting but the renderer I have does not seem to reference it. Perhaps there is something that needs to be done to link the renderer to the dataset when this type of override is happening?

```
    // ~~ Plot the Minute Average Data (avg, min, max)
    plot.setDataset(MINUTE_DATA, getMinuteDataset());
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(MINUTE_DATA, FILL_RANGE_AXIS);
    //XYLineAndShapeRenderer minuteRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer minuteRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
            System.out.println("get item paint");

            Paint cpaint = getItemColor(row, col);
            if (cpaint == null) {
                cpaint = super.getItemPaint(row, col);
            }
            return cpaint;
        }

        public Color getItemColor(int row, int col) {
            System.out.println(col + "," + dataset.getY(row, col));
            double y = dataset.getYValue(row, col);
            if(y<=3) return Color.black;
            if(y<=4) return Color.green;;
            if(y<=5) return Color.red;;
            if(y<=6) return Color.yellow;;
            if(y<=10) return Color.orange;;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void drawFirstPassShape(Graphics2D g2, int pass, int series,
            int item, Shape shape) {
            System.out.println("drawing first pass shape");

            g2.setStroke(getItemStroke(series, item));
            Color c1 = getItemColor(series, item);
            Color c2 = getItemColor(series, item - 1);
            GradientPaint linePaint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, 300, c2);
            g2.setPaint(linePaint);
            g2.draw(shape);
        }
    };
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(2, false);
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, XBLUE);
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesPaint(1, DODGER_BLUE);
    minuteRenderer.setSeriesPaint(2, DODGER_BLUE);
    plot.setRenderer(MINUTE_DATA, minuteRenderer);
```

executing the above gives me this null pointer error:

```
SEVERE: Uncaught exception thrown in java.awt.EventDispatchThread, thread: 14-AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at filtec.gui.widgets.fmsqa.FmsLtaChartPanel$1.getItemColor(FmsLtaChartPanel.java:234)
```

where dataset is null...

Comment: Did you try using Milliseconds?  For dashed check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247649/643500

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I'm not sure I under what is meant by using Milliseconds. The question you linked is exactly where I got my example that I am trying. I linked it in my OP.

Comment: Can you, please, post the complete code to reproduce with the dataset

Comment: You could override `drawFirstPassShape()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965997/230513).

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I've updated with the new override and am still getting a null pointer.

Comment: @trashgod the new override seems to yield a null pointer as well. I added a little more context in the description.

Comment: I was thinking you could use a transparent color for the missing _y_ values. Also consider a custom `Timeline` for your `DataAxis`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312264/230513). A [mcve] may allow you to study the problem is isolation.